# Gson disabling pretty printing for JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable pretty printing for JsonArray?
it comes out like this:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ]
}
```

when I want it to come out like this:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "array": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic difference between pretty-printing and formatting, so that I would rephrase the question to *why does Gson not support formatting*? Well, because it should not. Then, more, I'd say that you cannot implement an efficient formatter for complex objects to fit all of your style preferences. For example, there are many open questions: - are your arrays so simple so they only contain a sequence of numbers? - what if an array contains elements of various kinds and an object as its #10000 element only: how many JSON output to buffer for other elements, if the count is million? Etc, etc, etc... Well, don't bother for that, and merely either don't use pretty-printing for minified output, or use it for entire documents.

However, if you still think it's a good idea and it would cover your (probably not complex) needs, then using a custom `JsonWriter` extension may help:

```java
public final class FormattingJsonWriter
        extends JsonWriter {

    // TODO add more methods for more complex formatting if necessary: expose stack somehow, etc
    public interface IStrategy {

        String getIndentOnEnter(JsonToken jsonToken);

    }

    private final IStrategy formattingStrategy;
    private final Stack<String> indentStack = new Stack<>();

    private FormattingJsonWriter(@WillCloseWhenClosed final Writer out, final IStrategy formattingStrategy) {
        super(out);
        this.formattingStrategy = formattingStrategy;
    }

    public static JsonWriter create(@WillCloseWhenClosed final Writer out, final IStrategy formattingStrategy) {
        return new FormattingJsonWriter(out, formattingStrategy);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter beginArray()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.beginArray();
        final String indent = formattingStrategy.getIndentOnEnter(JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY);
        indentStack.push(indent);
        jsonWriter.setIndent(indent);
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter endArray()
            throws IOException {
        setIndent(indentStack.pop());
        return super.endArray();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter beginObject()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.beginObject();
        final String indent = formattingStrategy.getIndentOnEnter(JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT);
        indentStack.push(indent);
        jsonWriter.setIndent(indent);
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter endObject()
            throws IOException {
        setIndent(indentStack.pop());
        return super.endObject();
    }

}
```

```java
final JsonElement jsonElement = ...;
final Writer out = new StringWriter();
final JsonWriter jsonWriter = FormattingJsonWriter.create(out, jsonToken -> switch ( jsonToken ) {
    case BEGIN_ARRAY -> "";
    case BEGIN_OBJECT -> "\t";
    default -> throw new AssertionError();
});
Streams.write(jsonElement, jsonWriter);
System.out.println(out);
```

Note that the indentation, if set to non-empty, will always produce a new line in `JsonWriter`, otherwise there are no even whitespace between object and array elements.

You can try improving it, but I doubt it's worth doing that. Or try finding a dedicated formatting library. Gson is definitely not a good tool here.